# #Error field in query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am calculating Taxes being taken out of a check, and the net payment.

There are 4 tax percentages that are entered on a form, and I am using those to multiply against the Gross amount (either Payout, or Award). When I try to use the tax amounts alone, I receive #Error in the field when the query is ran.

The formulas are as follows:

```
FICATax: Format(IIf([MCR_EarningsCode]='LTF',
[MCR_AwardGross]*[Forms]![AstProfileFrm]![FicaTaxTxt],
[MCR_PytAmt]*[Forms]![AstProfileFrm]![FicaTaxTxt]),"Currency")

LocalTax: Format(IIf([MCR_EarningsCode]='LTF',
[MCR_AwardGross]*[Forms]![AstProfileFrm]![LocalTaxTxt],
[MCR_PytAmt]*[Forms]![AstProfileFrm]![LocalTaxTxt]),"Currency")
```

Now, when I try to use these 2 fields in my Net payment calculation, I receive #Error.

Net Payout formula:

```
NetPayment: Format(Round(IIf([MCR_EarningsCode]='LTF',
[FICATax]+[LocalTax], <-- Error 
[MCR_PytAmt]-[FederalTax]-[StateTax]-[FICATax]-[LocalTax]),2),"Currency") <-- This works
```

Sample data:

```
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+----------+
| MCR_AwardGross| EarningsCode | MCR_PytAmt | FederalTax | StateTax | FICATax | LocalTax |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+----------+
|#1) $34,000    |      LTF     |            |            |          | $340.00 |  $340.00 |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+----------+
|#2)            |      LTR     | $11,500.00 | $2,875.01  | $402.50  | $115.00 |  $115.00 |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+----------+
|#3)            |      LTR     | $8,341.60  | $2,085.40  | $291.96  | $83.42  |  $83.42  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

The results for Net Payment would be:

1. #Error    => `[FICATax]+[LocalTax]`
2. $2,992.55   => `[MCR_PytAmt]-[FederalTax]-[StateTax]-[FICATax]-[LocalTax]`
3. $5,797.40   => `[MCR_PytAmt]-[FederalTax]-[StateTax]-[FICATax]-[LocalTax]`

Personally, I don't see how it could be an issue with `Null` values, because there will never be a `Null` value in any of the calculations. Is there an issue with dealing with these fields at run time?

Note: I got it to work by adding a `0` in front of the calculation.

`0-[FICATax]-[LocalTax]` .. However, I am curious why it won't add the two 'fields?'

Comment: I suspect the problem stems from the fact that the `Format()` function converts a number to a string. In some cases Access will automatically convert strings back to numbers if we try to perform math with them. However, in your more complicated cases that appears to fail. Adding the '0-' prefix acts as a hint that the result should be numeric. Another possible fix would be to explicitly convert the strings (as produced by `Format()`) back into currency values with `CCur()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem stems from the fact that the `Format()` function converts a number to a string. In some cases Access will automatically convert strings back to numbers if we try to perform math with them. However, in your more complicated cases that appears to fail. Adding the '0-' prefix acts as a hint that the result should be numeric.

Another possible fix would be to explicitly convert the strings (as produced by `Format()`) back into currency values with `CCur()`. However, you may also reconsider whether you really want to format those values, especially if they will be used in subsequent calculations. I always recommend keeping numbers as numbers (and dates as dates) in queries. If you need special formatting you can always apply it at the *presentation* level, e.g., in the `.Format` property of a Text Box control on a Report.

Comment: Great suggestion, Gord. I didn't think of the `String` conversion. Formatting at the presentation level makes much more sense because all of the data types are remaining as one would assume, instead of being converted. Thanks again.